Подключение двух ethernet портов в windows 11
Доброго дня уважаемые господа и дамы. Уже пол года владею компом на базе мат платы Huanazhi X99 F8D PLUS, на ней имеется два ethernet порта по 2.5 Gb/s, в связи с чем у меня встает вопрос, можно ли их как то запаралелить чтоб нагрузка на них было относительно одинаковая и соответственно кратная скорость. Интернет провайдер у меня прекрасный и такое с него выжать реально, иногда в Speedtest OOKLA я ловлю цифры 1400-1600 Mb/s, но опять же иногда. Хотелось бы что то стабильное ибо скачивать и загружать приходится террабайты в день. Может кто то подсказать решение, может программу, скрипт, команды для cmd, впринципе что угодно. Заранее спасибо )

я ловлю цифры 1400-1600 Mb/s тоесть гигабайт канал я правильно понял?) Вообще странный вопрос, судя по запросам) 2.5 Gb/s что ВЦ серьезно??.... У вас дома прям дата центр.. Если у вас подключен такой канал интернета не по тому, что вас развели, а что реально надо... ну вы реально гоните с вопросом) даже джун такое не спросит..
Короче.. мат плата - китай (хоть и не плохой)... 2.5 G.b/s как-то ОООООчень сомнительно) как минимум учитывая роутер) По теме вопроса.. вы копаете не туда) мой личный совет, не можалейте 500р, возьмите среднего тренера и все сразу станет более понятно

Почти ВЦ, там долгая история. Я просто более менее прошарен в конкретной теме, на счет инета и подключений не особо, Сервера особо настраивать даже не пришлось, там само все работает, но и операционки там серверные и NAS, не удивительно. А вот как на десктоп плате реализовать тоже самое я ответа не нашел... касаемо роутера, в моем случае роутерОВ ибо приходит два провайдера, и тот и тот мне дают гигабит. роутеры отличные, свичи тоже. Я уже думал купить PCI затычку купить 10 Гб/с и в нее пустить, но они стоят как крыло от самолета... На счет тренера не понял.

на ней имеется два ethernet порта по 2.5 Gb/s Скорость портов - в гигабитах в секунду, а не в гигабайтах. 2.5 Gbps. Не верите - посмотрите характеристики установленных на матери чипов Realtek RTL8125BG. иногда в Speedtest OOKLA я ловлю цифры 1400-1600 Mb/s - это как минимум 13 Gbps. Так что вы ловите явно не фактическую скорость обмена, ибо порт не может дать скорость в 6 раз выше его физических фозможностей, а чёрт знает что. Например, скорость записи в кэш.

спидтест Mb - мегабиты , 1,4 гигабита.

@Jour Почему нет? У меня в квартиру заведено 2 оптических кабеля по 1.5 Гбит/с. Это сейчас не проблема. Другое дело, что бондинг я не делал, мне это не нужно. А вот на работе - 8 жил, с достаточно хитрым кроссингом. Биоинформатика - очень жрущая трафик наука :)

Нужен роутер с поддержкой бондинга. В Винде это называется nic teaming. Создаете бонд на роутере, создаете тиминг того же типа на виндовс и провода будут нагружены равномерно. Но стабильности это врятли добавит.
